# xml mandatory header: version and encoding

Tags: xml, header, version

Is it mandatory to add next xml header in an XML file to be well formed?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I already understand that it is better for parsing options and so on.

Comment: It is not mandatory, but it will be helpful for XML parser to know the actual encoding of your XML document, so you will not get unexpected results and errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML declaration is optional, but suggested, according to the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd).